# Why has lightdm-remote-session been removed from Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: lightdm, 15.04, vnc, remote-access, remote-x-session

Straightforward question, really.

I must admit I haven't used it much, but just recently had started doing. Now it's not in the repositories.

What's the thinking behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm-remote-session-freerdp/+publishinghistory) it was deleted by Adam Conrad because it was "buggy and unmaintained", citing unresolved security bugs like [1158373](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remote-login-service/+bug/1158373) as evidence of this.

Answer (score 1):

I read once there is some unsolved problems that prevent from using it for 15.04

The [official group](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/lightdm-remote-session-freerdp) states:

> There is no current release of this source package in The Vivid
>   Vervet. You can still report bugs, make translations, and so on, but
>   they might not be used until the package is published.